# PowerShell: Disabling Windows.Forms Resize

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I want to stop the end users from being able to resize a GUI that I've created.

```
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "ADX v2.1.2.0"
$objForm.minimumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(965,665) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$objForm.backcolor = "gray"
```

I've tried `$objform.resize = 'false'`, but that doesn't work.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$objForm.FormBorderStyle = 'None' or 'FixedDialog'

Answer (score 0):

So after a little messing aroud, I figured out that this is the easiest way to do it:

```
$objForm.minimumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(965,665) 
$objForm.maximumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(965,665)
```